# Project profiling-Leaks in iOS shows 2 leaks "Responsible caller -bsxpcserviceconnectionEventHandler"

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling, instruments

I got 2 leaks when I profiling with the device (not shown with the simulator) , even without touching the screen . The leaks described as :BoardServices -bsxpcserviceconnectionEventHandler. Any Explanation/Solution .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is : If you remove the sceneDelegate and the storyBoard, even if you delete the mainStoryBoard from the info.plist the leak-Instrument will show 2-leaks .